# Illegal string offset - Small issue

Tags: php

Yes I know this has been asked a zillion times but still left puzzled.

The bottom line in the code:

```
$this->labels[$row['id']] = $row['content'];
```

How can this be better written so as to avoid an illegal offset in php?

Trying to make sense of the PHP manual but confused..

Using TRUE as a key will evaluate to integer 1 as key. Using FALSE as a key will evaluate to integer 0 as key. Using NULL as a key will evaluate to an empty string. Using an empty string as key will create (or overwrite) a key with an empty string and its value, it is not the same as using empty brackets.

You cannot use arrays or objects as keys. Doing so will result in a warning:Illegal offset type.

Any good articles that I can read so as to correct this in future?

```
    $sql = "SELECT `l`.`id`, `c`.`content`
            FROM `{$this->table_2}` `l`
            LEFT JOIN  `{$this->table_3}` `c`
                ON `c`.`label` = `l`.`id`;
            WHERE `c`.`language` = ?
            ORDER BY `l`.`name` ASC";
            $labels = $this->Db->getAll($sql, $this->language);
            if (empty($labels)) {
                setcookie('lang', 1, time() + 31536000, '/');
                $this->language= 1;
    $sql = "SELECT `l`.`id`, `c`.`content`
            FROM `{$this->table_2}` `l`
            LEFT JOIN  `{$this->table_3}` `c`
            ON `c`.`label` = `l`.`id`
            WHERE `c`.`language` = ?
            ORDER BY `l`.`name` ASC";
            $labels = $this->Db->getAll($sql, $this->lanaguage);
            }
            if (!empty($labels)) {
                foreach($labels as $row) {
                 $this->labels[$row['id']] = $row['content'];
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)) php function as follows.

```
foreach($labels as $row) { 
  if( isset($row['id']) && isset($row['content']) ){
    $this->labels[$row['id']] = $row['content'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you heaps. I should of picked up on that. Worked great. Thanks :)